# How to match most specific string from a collection of strings

Tags: data-structures, suffix-tree

I want to search a collection of strings to find the most specific match from left to right. Each string can have some associated data that must be returned when a match occurs. Matches must be returned in the order of specificness. That is I should be able to iterate through matches in most specific to least specific order (other way is also ok).

For example for the set of string, data tuples:

```
"abc", data_1
"xyz", data_2
"abcpqr", data_3
"abcpqrstu", data_4
"xyzpqr", data_2
```

If I search for abcpqr, I should get following in most specific to least specific order:

```
"abcpqr", data_3
"abc", data_1
```

For abcpqrstu:

```
"abcpqrstu" : data_4
"abcpqr", data_3
"abc", data_1
```

For abcpq:

```
"abc", data_1
```

Can I use a suffix tree or any other data structure to do this?

Comment: Yes, suffix tree sounds a good idea. Did you try?

Comment: Is there a good and mature C++ library that you know of?